# Using delegate with tabBarController on Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Would appreciate any advice as I try and wrap my head around this -  I'm not sure if I'm implementing this wrong, or am working from the wrong premise (or both).

If I have a class in which I've created a protocol (the delegatOR) - in order to assign a delegate for that protocol, am I right to say I need to alloc/init the 'delegatee' class somewhere in the delegator's implementation file, and then assign it as the delegator's delegate?

If so, follow up question: I have a tabBarController set up in Storyboard, and when the user clicks on the 'end' tab I'd like to send a message to the viewController for the view they're about to leave, so it pops up an alert saying something like 'are you sure?'.  Since storyboard does the initializing and allocating behind the scenes, I'm at a loss as to how to set up the delegate.  I read in another posting about using the prepareForSegue method when segueing between two viewControllers to set the delegate, but can't work out a similar catch-and-set technique for the tabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a class in which I've created a protocol (the delegatOR) - in order to assign a delegate for that protocol, am I right to say I need to alloc/init the 'delegatee' class somewhere in the delegator's implementation file, and then assign it as the delegator's delegate?

No. The way it usually works is that some other class, usually some kind of controller, will instantiate (i.e. alloc/init) an object as well as its delegate, and set the object's delegate.

For example, if you have a `UITableView` and a `UITableViewDelegate`, typically you have some kind of view controller that owns the `UITableView`, and also owns the `UITableViewDelegate` (often the view controller itself is the delegate). It's the view controller's job to set the table view's delegate. It most certainly is not the `UITableView`'s job to create and set its delegate.

Still, you're right that setting delegates for view controllers can be hard when you're using Storyboard. If the `prepareForSegue:` method isn't working for you, I assume it's because the tab bar controller is your root view controller (as it well should be, according to the HIG). Since your app delegate will have a `window` property, you should be able to get to the root view controller from it:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.selectedIndex = [defaults integerForKey:kOptionLastTabSelectedKey];
tabController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yes - sorry, I was thinking of the last examples I'd been studying which involved creating a protocol, not using the custom cocoa delegates. What I was stumbling towards is that delegation must be done at the time of instantiation, which is pretty obvious now in retrospect - and yeah, makes it tricky when working with storyboard.  Another tricky thing about trying to learn this in the post-Storyboard world -  Storyboard-based dev doesn't seem to involve the app delegate nearly as much - will need to study up before giving your advice a go.  Thank you for the reply.